# Google Web Fonts - CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to include google web fonts in my style sheet rather than in the head tag of my page?

Also, is this recommended or is the head method a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and Google give you the code to copy/paste into your stylesheet. Click the `@import` tab.

Comment: why would anyone votedown this question? It's a valid question that he is allowed to ask here

Comment: @Timidfriendly Because of the obvious lack of research effort. Mouse over to the downvote button and see the tooltip.

Comment: @Antony I did research it and couldn't find it. Plus i was also asking what is the preferred method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the instructions:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab);
```

[image: @import]